# Angular 17 [vite] Internal server error: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: angular, angular-universal, angular-ssr

After upgrading from Angular 15 to 17 i keep getting this error.

> PM [vite] Internal server error: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
> at Function.getPrototypeOf ()
> at node_modules/whatwg-url/lib/utils.js (/home/dej/src/hi-frontend/node_modules/whatwg-url/lib/utils.js:34:39)
> at __require2 (/home/dej/src/hi-frontend/.angular/vite-root/hi-frontend/chunk-LO3AJX6B.mjs:54:50)
> at node_modules/whatwg-url/lib/URL.js (/home/dej/src/hi-frontend/node_modules/whatwg-url/lib/URL.js:4:15)
> at __require2 (/home/dej/src/hi-frontend/.angular/vite-root/hi-frontend/chunk-LO3AJX6B.mjs:54:50)
> at node_modules/whatwg-url/webidl2js-wrapper.js (/home/dej/src/hi-frontend/node_modules/whatwg-url/webidl2js-wrapper.js:3:13)
> at __require2 (/home/dej/src/hi-frontend/.angular/vite-root/hi-frontend/chunk-LO3AJX6B.mjs:54:50)
> at node_modules/whatwg-url/index.js (/home/dej/src/hi-frontend/node_modules/whatwg-url/index.js:3:34)
> at __require2 (/home/dej/src/hi-frontend/.angular/vite-root/hi-frontend/chunk-LO3AJX6B.mjs:54:50)
> at node_modules/jsdom/lib/api.js (/home/dej/src/hi-frontend/node_modules/jsdom/lib/api.js:7:19) (x2)

After narrowing it down I found that its this code that leads to the error:

```
new User().deserialize(user)
```

Basically everywhere through out my app where i call the deserialize() function, this error keeps happening.

Example: The get functions in my services all use the deserialize() methods:

```
getUser(): Observable<User> {
    let url = this.domain + this.prefix + '/user/';
    return this.http.get<User>(url).pipe(
        map(user => new User().deserialize(user))
    );
}
```

If I for example don't call deserialize() on the response from the server the error goes away. But I need to use deserialize() as I have implemented this on hundreds of places through out the app...

The User class looks like this:

```
export interface Deserializable {
    deserialize(input: any): this;
}

export class User implements Deserializable {
    id: number;

    deserialize(input: any): this {
        Object.assign(this, input);
        return this;
    }

    getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
}
```

I tried adding checks for null or undefined in deserialize but its still not working:

```
deserialize(input: any): this {
    if (input == null || input == undefined)
        return this;

    Object.assign(this, input);
    return this;
}
```

Any ideas why this is causing the error?

Comment: TBH, this is a weird deserialization logic (IMO, of course). Inside of `getUser(…)`, inside the `map((user) => …)`, is `user` parameter and object? Do you know its properties? Are they static (known in advance)? If so, create an interface for it. If `User` the interface, then create the instance _after_ getting the relevant properties of `user` (don't pre-create an instance).

Comment: Assuming the error is somewhere in the given code (which it might not be), `Object.assign(…)` only throws such error when _the first argument_ is nullish (i.e., `Object.assign({}, null)` doesn't throw). Since the first argument is always `this`, there is a possibility of `this` being `undefined` in case if you extract `deserialize` method out of the object and call it without the context: `const { deserialize } = new User(); deserialize(something)`. Try to find similar approach in your codebase. If there isn't such, the error is not in the provided code.

Comment: Thanks, the error gets more weird, i narrowed it down to removing almost everything and ending up with a simple User class that has no deserialize method and still, if I simply call `const user = new User()`it will throw this error :/ also noted in the beginning of the error this line: 
[vite] Error when evaluating SSR module /main.server.mjs:
|- TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.getPrototypeOf (<anonymous>)
    at node_modules/whatwg-url/lib/utils.js (/home/dej/src/hi-frontend/node_modules/whatwg-url/lib/utils.js:34:39)

Comment: It seems to be an SSR related issue! by removing SSR the issue disappears...

Comment: Found it, the error was related to an import of an external package that SSR didn't like. Somehow this expressed itself everywhere where there was a class that was initiated like `new User()`... Once i removed the bad import, all these errors went away.